# import Excel sheet Data into Alfresco Datalist

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts

I have more than 1000 records in excel sheet.
now i want to add those records into data list in alfresco. But it seems to be very bad practice to copy those records one by one to data-list. so is there any way to import all records from excel to data-list in alfresco.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please reply, either is is possible or not??

Comment: Out of the box, no. It's probably a few hours work if you're sure there are no duplicates, longer if you need to handle duplicates somehow

Comment: Ok Gagravarr,  Thanks for reply

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A5H1ofKbDjg